# Sort by most equal texts

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have a table and I need to sort the rows according to the most frequent occurrences of a word, yes. The more yes, it will be a line at the top spot and limit the number of lines to five.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | logo       |  feature1    |   feature2     |   feature3    | feature4
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | img1.png   |   yes    |   yes          |   yes          |   info
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | img2.png   |   no     |   no           |   no          |   yes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  | img3.png   |   yes    |   info          |   yes         |   info
------------------------------------------------------------------------
4  | img4.png   |   yes    |   yes          |   info        |   yes
```

First row with ID 1 or 4
Second row with ID 1 or 4
Third row with ID 3
Fourth row with ID 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should give you what you want:

```
select id, logo, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4
from your_table
order by ((feature1='yes') + (feature2='yes') + (feature3='yes') + (feature4='yes')) desc
limit 5
```

Comment: Database respond: Error in query: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean + boolean
LINE 3: order by ((instant_setup='yes') + (pay_as_you_go='yes') + (i...
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You tagged your question "mysql" so I gave you an answer for MySQL, but your error implies you are using something else.

Answer (score 0):

Put a FULLTEXT index on all feature columns and do a simple boolean search

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD FULLTEXT idx_name (feature1, feature2, feature3,feature4);

 SELECT * FROM T WHERE MATCH (feature1, feature2, feature3,feature4) AGAINST ('word');
```

Pay attention to [stop word list and minimum word length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: Wont that just return rows where there is a match on the selected word in the specified columns - rather than order it according to the number of matches.

Comment: @PaulF "By default (when neither + nor - is specified), the word is optional, but the rows that contain it are rated higher" It`s in the docs,one thing it might need is an ORDER BY MATCH..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I had only seen it used with ORDER BY - so assumed that was required.